# {{{∅}}}=2 True or false?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

1. $0=\emptyset$
2. $1=\{\emptyset\}$
3. $2=\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\}\}$

This understood, would $\{\{\{\emptyset\}\}\}$ also contain 2 elements? Such that $\{\{\},\{\emptyset\}\}\subset\{\{\{\emptyset\}\}\}$?

If so, then would $\{\{\{\{\emptyset\}\}\}\}=3$ and so forth?

Comment: Under your definition of $0$, we have $\{\{\{0\}\}\}=\{\{\{\varnothing\}\}\}$. This contains a single element, namely $\{\{\varnothing\}\}$.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The set $\{\{...\{\{x\}\}...\}\}$ only has one element despite the nesting.

Comment: these numbers are von neumann ordinals

Comment: See [Zermelo ordinals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_number#Zermelo_ordinals)

Answer (score 1):

No. The set $\{\emptyset, \{\emptyset\}\}$ has **two** elements. The set $\{\{\{\emptyset\}\}\}$ has only one element, so the two sets are not identical.

Comment: I am agree with you and with the comments.